# How to add vertical spacing in pandoc table containing chemical figures?

Tags: tables, chemfig, pandoc

I want to produce a table in pandoc-markdown which contains some chemical figures I created using chemfig.

This is my MWE:

````
---
header-includes:
- |
  ```{=latex}
  \usepackage{chemfig}
  ```
---
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

C |Name            |Sum Formula |Structural Formula
--|----------------|------------|--------------
2 |Ethen (=Ethylen)|C~2~H~4~    | \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)-[7]H}
3 |Propen          |C~3~H~6~    | \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[2]H)-[1]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
4 |1-Buten         |C~4~H~8~    | \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[2]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
5 |1-Pentan        |C~5~H~10~   | \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[2]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
````

It produces this output:

[image: output]

As you can see, it mostly gets the spacing right, exept in the line with Propen, where the formula has a very big height. I've experimented with other values for arraystretch. When I set it to 9, it produces a visible space betwen the formulas in row 2 and 3, but then i'd be wasting lots of space in the other rows.

How can I use the same space betwen all rows, no matter the height of the formulas they contain?

Answer (score 2):

If you add an "invisible bond" to the hydrogen of ethylene, you will create a vertical space. You can adjust the length of the bond to adjust the vertical space

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

C |Name            |Sum Formula |Structural Formula
--|----------------|------------|--------------
2 |Ethen (=Ethylen)|C~2~H~4~    | \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[1]H)-[7]H-[6,,,,draw=none]}% invisible bond
3 |Propen          |C~3~H~6~    | \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[2]H)-[1]C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
4 |1-Buten         |C~4~H~8~    | \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[2]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
5 |1-Pentan        |C~5~H~10~   | \chemfig{C(-[3]H)(-[5]H)=C(-[2]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
```